# How is GSON creating an instance of a no-zero-arg constructor class?

Tags: java, reflection, gson

In the following example, GSON appears to be able to create an instance of Program (`p` in the program below) without the use of the declared constructor while also no other zero-arg constructor is present.  How is this accomplished by the library?

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Program
{
    private final String _id;

    private Program(String id)
    {
        System.out.println("Constructor called.");
        _id = id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = "{\"_id\":\"id1\"}";
        Program p = gson.fromJson(json, Program.class);

        System.out.println(p._id);

        boolean noArgConstructorAvailable;
        try
        {
            Object ctor = Program.class.getConstructor();
            noArgConstructorAvailable = ctor != null;
        }
        catch(NoSuchMethodException e)
        {
            noArgConstructorAvailable = false;
        }

        System.out.println(noArgConstructorAvailable);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
id1
false
```